# Regex: accurately match bold (**) and italics (*) item(s) from the input

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown, typography

I am trying to parse a markdown content with the use of regex. To grab **bold** and *italic* items from the input, I'm currently using a regex:

```js
/(\*\*)(?<bold>[^**]+)(\*\*)|(?<normal>[^`*[~]+)|\*(?<italic>[^*]+)\*/g
```

Regex101 Link: https://regex101.com/r/2zOMid/1

###### The problem with this regex are:

- if there is a single `*` in between a bold text content, the match is breaked
- if there are long texts like `*******` anywhere in between the match is broken

#####: tried with:
I tried removing the `[^**]` part in the `bold` group but that messed up the bold match with finding the last `**` occurrence and including all `**`` chars within

###### What I want to have:

- accurate bold
- `*` allowed inside bold
- accurate italics

Language: Javascript

###### Assumptions:

Bold text wrapped inside `**`
Italic text wrapped inside `*`

Comment: Do not use a single regex here since matches are overlapping. Use bold regex first, then italics.

Comment: yes, i'm trying to do the same. for that the bold match in the above regex should allow to contain single `*` char within. if I do that the bold match is messed up. can i do that properly with regex?

Comment: Shouldn't one, by markdown rules, in need to literally show an asterisk `*` escape it? `***\****` for the exact reason?

Comment: for me, `*****` & `**\***` means a normal text. If we want just an asterisk as bold maybe using raw HTML is better (markdown supports that). but if the input is like `**ab*cd**` then `ab*cd` should be a match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was some [discussion in the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/246501/2022/7/17) going on. Just to have it mentioned, there is no requirement yet on how to deal with escaped characters like `\*` so I didn't take attention of it.

Depending on the desired outcome I'd pick a two step solution and keep the patterns simple:

```
str = str.replace(/\*\*(.+?)\*\*(?!\*)/g,'<b>$1</b>').replace(/\*([^*><]+)\*/g,'<i>$1</i>');
```

- **Step 1**: Replace bold parts
  Replace `\*\*(.+?)\*\*(?!\*)`  with `<b>$1</b>` -> [Regex101
  demo](https://regex101.com/r/xNwndD/1)
  It [captures](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(.+?)` [one or more](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) [characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) between `**` [lazily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2301291/5527985) to [`$1`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)
  and uses a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for matching the outher most `*` at the end.
- **Step 2**: Now as the amount of remaining `*` is reduced, *italic* parts
  Replace remaining `\*([^*><]+)\*` to `<i>$1</i>` -> [Regex101
  demo](https://regex101.com/r/OIeRw1/1)
  `[^*><]+` matches *one or more* [characters that are not](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `*`, `>` or `<`.

[Here is the JS-demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##TY7BboMwEETv/oqpVAmyoaDeqoaQU78ipJIhBlwZjGwnOVT9drrQBPXgWc/4ebRf8ip97fQYXq5v02RUgA/OY4@jiLztFQbremkghzOIKmvOuOnQgdCqnohQXQLGi1MgHaTRtSdoHyUiokXu@hiP2VjLbdKtydy8Gsm9HK20ZFv9vZ52Qswbpo11H7LuYjbYF@JbAFmGcLMYpffvaLTzAXNtgtCpAff1mFu@zJo6NRpZqzgrqaQ43R42y@XwVNImaxNEeVU8v@ZZVUSb/3B8/KQiP20ZZyzK9UJppnbcX9vBW6NSY9t5Pc5@@Ihp@gU)

Myself I don't think it's a good idea to rely on the amount of the same character for distinguishing between kinds of replacement. The way how it works finally gets a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

`[^**]` will not avoid *two consecutive* `*`. It is a character class that is no different from `[^*]`. The repeated asterisk has no effect.

The pattern for italic should better come in front of the normal part, which should capture anything that remains. This could even be a sole asterisk (for example) -- the pattern for normal text should allow this.

It will be easier to use `split` and use the bold/italic pattern for matching the "delimiter" of the split, while still capturing it. All the rest will then be "normal". The downside of `split` is that you cannot benefit from named capture groups, but they will just be represented by separate entries in the returned array.

I will ignore the other syntax that markdown can have (like you seem to hint at with `[` and `~` in your regex). On the other hand, it is important to deal well with backslash, as it is used to escape an asterisk.

Here is the regular expression (link):

[`(\*\*?)(?![\s\*])((?:[\s*]*(?:\\[\\*]|[^\\\s*]))+?)\1`](https://regex101.com/r/lbI52l/1)

Here is a snippet with two functions:

- a function that first splits the input into tokens, where each token is a pair, like `["normal", " this is normal text "]` and `["i", "text in italics"]`
- another function that uses these tokens to generate HTML

The snippet is interactive. Just type the input, and the output will be rendered in HTML using the above sequence.

```js
function tokeniseMarkdown(s) {
    const regex = /(\*\*?)(?![\s\*])((?:[\s*]*(?:\\[\\*]|[^\\\s*]))+?)\1/gs;
    const styles = ["i", "b"];
    // Matches follow this cyclic order: 
    //   normal text, mark (= "*" or "**"), formatted text, normal text, ...
    const types = ["normal", "mark", ""];
    return s.split(regex).map((match, i, matches) =>
        types[i%3] !== "mark" && match &&
            [types[i%3] || styles[matches[i-1].length-1], 
             match.replace(/\\([\\*])/g, "$1")]
    ).filter(Boolean); // Exclude empty matches and marks
}

function tokensToHtml(tokens) {
    const container = document.createElement("span");
    for (const [style, text] of tokens) {
        let node = style === "normal" ? document.createTextNode(text) 
                                      : document.createElement(style);
        node.textContent = text;
        container.appendChild(node);
    }
    return container.innerHTML;
}


// I/O management
document.addEventListener("input", refresh);

function refresh() {
    const s = document.querySelector("textarea").value;
    const tokens = tokeniseMarkdown(s);
    document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = tokensToHtml(tokens);
}
refresh();
```

```css
textarea { width: 100%; height: 6em }
div { font: 22px "Times New Roman" }
```

```html
<textarea>**fi*rst b** some normal text here **second b**  *first i* normal *second i* normal again</textarea><br>

<div></div>
```

Comment: THX @trincot for the comment and the snippet. I'm trying to get this just by regex. At one point in your answer you mentioned about `which should capture anything that remains.` can i do that with regex? Like /oneGroup|anotherGroup|everyThingElse/`.

Comment: In JavaScript you can only do that if *everyThingElse* is a really smart pattern that captures anything up to the point where the previous groups would start a match. This is not maintainable as you would add more groups and/or more complexity to them. A second option is to let *anything else* just grab **one** character. That means you'll have a lot of single character matches that are consecutive, and then you need to join those again.

Comment: *"I'm trying to get this just by regex"*: yes, I just added a snippet to illustrate how you can use the result of the regex. The regex itself will identify all bold and italic parts, and also the surrounding marks (`**`), and it will skip normal parts. This is what I understood was the goal of your question -- to grab bold and italic parts.

Answer (score 1):

Looking some more about the negative lookaheads, I came up with this regex:

```
/\*\*(?<bold>(?:(?!\*\*).)+)\*\*|`(?<code>[^`]+)`|~~(?<strike>(?:(?!~~).)+)~~|\[(?<linkTitle>[^]]+)]\((?<linkHref>.*)\)|(?<normal>[^`[*~]+)|\*(?<italic>[^*]+)\*|(?<tara>[*~]{3,})|(?<sitara>[`[]+)/g
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tOchgH/1)

this pretty much works for me as per my input scenarios. If someone has a more optimized regex, please comment.

Comment: How would you use markdown to have a part in bold that ends with an asterisk, like **hey\***?

Comment: I would use `<b>hey*</b>` for that type of requirement

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the tags depending on the number of asterisks. (1 → italic, 2 → bold, 3 → bold+italic)

```js
function simpleMarkdownTransform(markdown) {
  return markdown
    .replace(/</g, '&lt') // disallow tags
    .replace(/>/g, '&gt')
    .replace(
      /(\*{1,3})(.+?)\1(?!\*)/g,
      (match, { length: length }, text) => {
        if (length !== 2) text = text.italics()
        return length === 1 ? text : text.bold()
      }
    )
    .replace(/\n/g, '<br>') // new line
}
```

Example:

```
simpleMarkdownTransform('abcd **bold** efgh *italic* ijkl ***bold-italic*** mnop') 
// "abcd <b>bold</b> efgh <i>italic</i> ijkl <b><i>bold-italic</i></b> mnop"
```

Answer (score 0):

italic: `((?<!\s)\*(?!\s)(?:(?:[^\*\*]*(?:(?:\*\*[^\*\*]*){2})+?)+?|[^\*\*]+?)(?<!\s)\*)`

`(?<!\s)\*(?!\s)` means matching the start * with no space around,
`(?:(?:[^\*\*]*(?:(?:\*\*[^\*\*]*){2})+?)+?` means match ** with even appearance, by which negalates meaningless ** inside intalic.
`|[^\*\*]+?` means if there's no match for one or more ** pair, match anything except a single **.(this "or" order is important)
(?<!\s)*) means matching the end * with no space ahead
And ?: is non-capturing group in js, you can delete it if not needing

bold:
`((?<!\s)\*\*(?!\s)(?:[^\*]+?|(?:[^\*]*(?:(?:\*[^\*]*){2})+?)+?)(?<!\s)\*\*)`

Similar to italic, except the order of * pair and other character.

Together you can get:
`((?<!\s)\*(?!\s)(?:(?:[^\*\*]*(?:(?:\*\*[^\*\*]*){2})+?)+?|[^\*\*]+?)(?<!\s)\*)|((?<!\s)\*\*(?!\s)(?:[^\*]+?|(?:[^\*]*(?:(?:\*[^\*]*){2})+?)+?)(?<!\s)\*\*)`

See the result here: https://regex101.com/r/9gTBpj/1

Comment: Tried the regex, no match found. See https://regex101.com/r/EX5cKI/1

Comment: (?<!\s)\*(?!\s) means matching the start * with no space around, so if it's around space, it won't match. if you don't want this feature, just try `(\*(?:(?:[^\*\*]*(?:(?:\*\*[^\*\*]*){2})+?)+?|[^\*\*]+?)\*)|(\*\*(?:[^\*]+?|(?:[^\*]*(?:(?:\*[^\*]*){2})+?)+?)\*\*)`

Comment: view it here https://regex101.com/r/9gTBpj/1